# Why does flutter_insta only return last 12 feed photos

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to know why flutter_insta package only returns last 12 post from someones feed when printed like following:

```
await flutterInsta.getProfileData(username);
        print("Profile data saved");
        setState(() {
          this.images = flutterInsta.feedImagesUrl;
        });
```

I have looked at the packages code and have seen this

```
_feedImagesUrl = user['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges'].map<String>((image) => image['node']['display_url'] as String).toList();
```

But honestly, I don't understand much of it.

Answer (score 0):

From https://instagram-private-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/instagram_web_api/client.html 
default value is `12` 
code snippet

```
def user_feed(self, user_id, **kwargs):
        """
        Get user feed

        :param user_id:
        :param kwargs:
            - **count**: Number of items to return. Default: 12
            - **end_cursor**: For pagination. Taken from:

                .. code-block:: python

                    info.get('data', {}).get('user', {}).get(
                        'edge_owner_to_timeline_media', {}).get(
                        'page_info', {}).get('end_cursor')
            - **extract**: bool. Return a simple list of media
        :return:
        """
        count = kwargs.pop('count', 12)
```

In issue of `flutter_insta` package `can u try implementing getting more than 12 profile images if they exist` https://github.com/viralvaghela/flutter_insta/issues/12 
Package owner has tag `To do`